# no pop up when right click

Tags: mouse

There is no pop up menu when I right click. I have set right button to secondary button as in the following picture.

Using ctrl+left click, there is a pop up menu so I can copy/paste selected or do some other tasks.

What I am doing wrong? I am using 10.6.8 on iMac.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed (or not properly uninstalled) some other pointing device drivers like USB Overdrive?

Comment: I don't think so. I have used external USB drives, that's all.

Comment: have you tried a different mouse?

Comment: No, but I found the mouse is fine. Please my related question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85043/need-to-set-mouse-setting-to-default

Answer (score 1):

If indeed you have a [Mighty Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Mighty_Mouse) as pictured in that screenshot, it's possible that the capitative sensors aren't properly detecting the right click action.

The most common cause of this was still having your left-click finger on the mouse, or resting very close, which I recall confused the sensors a bit. Try right clicking with only one finger touching the mouse and see if that helps. If not, it's possible that it's simply a hardware failure.

Comment: No. When a select some words, so it is highlighted by blue color. And then I right click above it, it just un-highlight the selected words. Left click do the same thing.

Comment: That could still be that the right button is registering as left when your fingers are both down. See [this article](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/02/01/solutions-for-fixing-a-mighty-mouse-that-wont-right-click-reliably/) for some more suggestions.

Comment: Finally, I just put the ball of the mouse on a white paper and roll it very very angry for a while, and now it works and I am not angry anymore.....